# PyOpenGL multitexture error - invalid operation

Tags: python, opengl, python-3.x, pygame, pyopengl

I'm trying to make a game that uses pygame and OpenGL in python 3, but i keep getting the same error:

```
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glClear,
    cArguments = (16640,)
)
```

Here is my code:

PART A - Create and Configure

```
Surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT),  pygame.OPENGL)

glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
glLoadIdentity()
gluOrtho2D(-8.0, 8.0, -6.0, 6.0)
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
glLoadIdentity()

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
glClearDepth(1.0)
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
```

PART B - Creating Texture

```
class Texture():
    # simple texture class
    # designed for 32 bit png images (with alpha channel)
    def __init__(self,fileName):
        self.texID=0
        self.LoadTexture(fileName)

    def LoadTexture(self,fileName): 
        try:
            textureSurface = pygame.image.load(fileName).convert_alpha()
            textureData = pygame.image.tostring(textureSurface, "RGBA", True)

            self.w, self.h = textureSurface.get_size()

            self.texID=glGenTextures(1)

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texID)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR)
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR)
            glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textureSurface.get_width(), 
                         textureSurface.get_height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                         textureData )

        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
            print ("can't open the texture: %s"%(fileName))

    def __del__(self):
        glDeleteTextures(self.texID)

    def get_width(self):
        return self.w

    def get_height(self):
        return self.h
```

PART C - Prepering the screen

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glLoadIdentity()
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

PART D - Adding Texture

```
def blit(texture, x, y):
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0.0)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.texID)
```

I looked it up, and apparently PyOpenGL 3 has this unfixed bug when try to render more than one texture. I use python 3.3, and dont wanna downgrade to 2.x, and i cant find a OpenGL 2 for python 3. Is there an away around this bug? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: it says it's happening at "glClear" so I assume you didn't create the OpenGL context yet, which you need to do before you make any calls to OpenGL

Comment: The code actually is in the order that is executed, so in PART A i had defined the openGL context

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) is thread local.  If you try to invoke an OpenGL statement from another thread without making current the OpenGL context current, you will get an *INVALID_OPERATION* error.
Unfortunately, PyGame does not offer a function to make the OpenGL context explicitly current.

Another possibility is that you missed closing a `glBegin`/glEnd`sequence with`glEnd` somewhere.